# How to use a class within a cron job function

Tags: cron

- I have cron jobs successfully working in WordPress,
- However, when I attempt to call a class from within the cron function it doesn't run.
- How would I call in a class with a cron job function?

---

```
add_action( 'hourly_event', 'hourly_function' );
function hourly_function() {
   // This otherwise works when not within a cron job function
   $newClass = new newClass();
   $newClass->newClass_function($var1, $var2, $var3); 
}
```

$newClass is declared within plugin.

---

```
require plugin_ROOT.'gd-text/Box.php';
require plugin_ROOT.'gd-text/Color.php';
require plugin_ROOT.'gd-text/HorizontalAlignment.php';
require plugin_ROOT.'gd-text/TextWrapping.php';
require plugin_ROOT.'gd-text/VerticalAlignment.php';

use GDText\Box;
use GDText\Color;


class newClass {

    public function newClass_function($var1, $var2, $var3){
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the log showing an error for that call?  Also, and it may be a typo here, but you are missing the parans on your class instantiation.  It should be `$newClass = new newClass();`

Comment: Yes, just a typo. And no error gets shown in php log.

Comment: How to do you declare `newClass` class and where?

Comment: It is declared in a plugin. See edited answer for specific code.

Comment: What is the hourly_event action? I don't believe that is a standard Wordpress hook. 
And for a Wordpress cron to work you need to have someone or something hitting your site to trigger it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling a function with variables that are not defined and are required for the function to work correctly.

```
function hourly_function() {

   $newClass = new newClass();

   $var1 = 'this should';
   $var2 = 'work with';
   $var3 = 'some content';

   $newClass->newClass_function($var1, $var2, $var3); 
}
```

You might want to move those variable to a `__construct`

```
if ( ! class_exists('AClass')) {
    class AClass {
        function __construct( $var1 = null, $var2 = null, $var3 = null ) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
$instance = new AClass(1,2,3);
```

Or the `__invoke` method:

```
if ( ! class_exists('BClass')) {
    class BClass {
        function __invoke( $var1 = null, $var2 = null, $var3 = null ) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
$instance = new BClass();
$instance(1,2,3);
```